# Start a public PHP server using CMD (Windows)

Tags: php, server-side

How do I start a `PHP public server` using `Command Prompt` (I'm using windows).
If I use `PHP -S localhost:<port>` it runs the server on my own `localhost` but no one outside my connection can access it, but I want my friend in the US to access it.
How do I do that using `Command Prompt`

**I have not yet tried anything yet**

Answer (score 0):

You can try use localhost tunneling with [ngrok.io](https://ngrok.com/) or [pagekite](https://pagekite.net/)

Comment: But ngrok will keep changing the domain and also I will have to keep restarting the server every 8hrs

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your router's configuration, ie.:

- link internal IP (e.g. `192.168.0.XXX`) and port (e.g. `80`) to your external/public IP. BTW, better to use non-standard HTTP port on the outside due to security issues. You can find these settings when login to router and go to *Settings->NAT Forwarding / Virtual servers*.

Your friend can then access `http://<YOUR_PUBLIC_IP>:<YOUR_PUBLIC_PORT>` from his/her browser. If you are concerned with dynamic IP, you should register with Dynamic DNS Provider (DDNS) for example: https://www.dynu.com/